# Programmatically (C#) convert Excel to an list of image

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com-interop, openxml-sdk

How to  convert an Microsoft excel (.xlsx) file to an PPT

My intended Algorithm

**Get charts** in Excel file  programmatically (c#). and save in **list of images**

Currently I'm using Microsoft Interop Libraries , even through i dont like i dont have any free alternative for this task

So my current work-around is as follows:

Open Excel file using Microsoft Interop;

Find all Charts in excel

Use the CopyPicture() on that chart , which will copy the data to the Clipboard.

once we have images in list we can add that into new powerpoint file 
creating new PPT document

Please let me know how add to Clipboard to Image list

```
public List<Image> Chartimages;
public List<Metafile> ChartimagesMetafile;

public List<BitmapSource> ChartimagesBitmapSource;

    public void InsertChartIntoChartlist()
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create an instance of PowerPoint.
                    powerpointApplication = new pptNS.Application();

                    // Create an instance Excel.
                    excelApplication = new xlNS.Application();

                    // Open the Excel workbook containing the worksheet with the chart

                    // data.
                    excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(paramWorkbookPath,
                                                         paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                                                         paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                                                         paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                                                         paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                                                         paramMissing, paramMissing);

                    // Get the worksheet that contains the chart.
                    targetSheet = (xlNS.Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets[2]);

                    // Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.

                    chartObjects = (xlNS.ChartObjects)(targetSheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));

                    foreach (xlNS.ChartObject item in chartObjects)
                    {
                        //    // Get the chart to copy.
                        existingChartObject = (xlNS.ChartObject)(item);

                        // Copy the chart from the Excel worksheet to the clipboard.

                        existingChartObject.CopyPicture(xlNS.XlPictureAppearance.xlPrinter, xlNS.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture);

                        if (Clipboard.ContainsData(System.Windows.DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile))
                        {
                            Metafile metafile = Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile) as Metafile;
                            //  metafile.Save(fileName);
                            ChartimagesMetafile.Add(metafile);
                        }
                        else if (Clipboard.ContainsData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Bitmap))
                        {
                            BitmapSource bitmapSource = Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Bitmap) as BitmapSource;

                            ChartimagesBitmapSource.Add(bitmapSource);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Finally, to whoever downvoted this: We were all learning one day, how to do something as a beginner is most definitely programming related, regardless of how new someone might be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  solution :

Get charts in Excel file programmatically (C#). and save in **list of images**

Create Class called ImageWithImageName to hold Images along with name

```
class ImageWithImageName
    {
       public Image ChartimagesBitmapSource;
        public string Filename;
        public ImageWithImageName(Image pramChartimagesBitmapSource, string pramFilename)
        {
            ChartimagesBitmapSource = pramChartimagesBitmapSource;
            Filename = pramFilename;
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
 public List<ImageWithImageName> ChartImages;
```

Create method to add all charts to   ChartImages list array

public void InsertChartIntoExcel()
        {
            try
            {

```
            // Create an instance Excel.
            excelApplication = new xlNS.Application();

            // Open the Excel workbook containing the worksheet with the chart
            // data.
            excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(paramWorkbookPath,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing);

            // Get the worksheet that contains the chart.
            targetSheet = (xlNS.Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets[2]);

            // Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.
            chartObjects = (xlNS.ChartObjects)(targetSheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));

            // Create a PowerPoint presentation.
            //pptPresentation = powerpointApplication.Presentations.Add(
            //                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            int i = 1;
            foreach (xlNS.ChartObject item in chartObjects)
            {
                //    // Get the chart to copy.
                existingChartObject = (xlNS.ChartObject)(item);

                string chartname = item.Name;

                existingChartObject.CopyPicture(xlNS.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, xlNS.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);

// contains in Clipboard so extract from clipboard 

                if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
                {


                    var image = Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Bitmap) as Image;
                    if (image != null)
                    {
                        ChartImages.Add(new ImageWithImageName(image, chartname + ".png"));
                    }
                }



                i++;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {


            // Release the Excel objects.
            targetSheet = null;
            chartObjects = null;
            existingChartObject = null;

            // Close and release the Excel Workbook object.
            if (excelWorkBook != null)
            {
                excelWorkBook.Close(false, paramMissing, paramMissing);
                excelWorkBook = null;
            }

            // Quit Excel and release the ApplicationClass object.
            if (excelApplication != null)
            {
                excelApplication.Quit();
                excelApplication = null;
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
```

Now I have Images in List of Images so , now we can Create a new Powerpoint file for this images

FYI: we can add Images to PPT via **Open xml** why COM Interop to Create an PPT

Happy coding 
Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code to Copy the chart; tested by pasting into a Word document. The Powerpoint part should fall in place.

```
public void InsertChartIntoChartlist()
{
    try
    {
        // Create an instance of PowerPoint.
        var powerpointApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

        // Create an instance Excel.
        var excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // Open the Excel workbook containing the worksheet with the chart data.
        var excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Book1.xlsx");

        // Get the worksheet that contains the chart.
        var targetSheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets[2];

        // Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.
        var chartObjects = targetSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject item in chartObjects)
        {
            item.Copy();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```